# mips: $v0 returns 0 instead of array pointer

Tags: assembly, mips

Hey I am new to frame pointers, so I have a doubt that something is wrong with frame pointer primarily in count_sort_calculate_counts function. What I am trying to do here is to return an array of integers. Any idea how to store array as an array of unspecified length?

*Result:*
line 112: Runtime exception at 0x004000c4: fetch address not aligned on word boundary 0x00000001

```
.data
list: .word 1, 3, 4, 2, 5, 6, 7, 9, 8, 0
size: .word 10
max_val: .word 10
snt: .asciiz ": "
nln: .asciiz "\n"

.text
main:
    la $a0, list
    la $a1, size
    lw $a1, 0($a1)
    jal count_sort
    
    move $a0, $v0
    la $a1, size
    lw $a1, 0($a1)
    jal print_list

# void count_sort (int *input, int i, int max_val) {
#   int *temp = (int *) malloc (max_val * sizeof(int));
#   count_sort_calculate_counts (input, temp, &i);
#   count_sort_fill_values (input, temp, i);
#   free(temp);

# $a0: address of list
# $a1: size of list
# $v0: address of sorted list

count_sort:
    # addi $sp, $sp, -4 # malloc(sizeof(int *address))
    # sw $ra, 0($sp) # address of count_sort
    la $s0, 0($ra) # address saved
    
    jal count_sort_calculate_counts # $v0 = count_sort_calculate_counts(...)
    
    move $a0, $v0 # input = temp
    move $a1, $v1 # size = max 
    addi $a1, $a1, 1 # size++
    jal count_sort_fill_values # $v0 = count_sort_fill_values(...)
    
    la $ra, 0($s0) # address resaved
    # lw $ra, 0($sp) # address of count_sort
    # addi $sp, $sp, 4 # free(address)
    jr $ra # return 

# void count_sort_calculate_counts (int *input, int *temp, int *i) {
#   for (int j = 0; j < *i; j++) {
#       temp[input[j]] = temp[input[j]] + 1;
#       // *(temp+*(input+j))++ 
#   }
# }     
    
# $a0: address of list
# $a1: address of size of list
# $v0: address of temp list
# $v1: max value of list

count_sort_calculate_counts: 
    addi $sp, $sp, -4 # malloc(sizeof(int *fp))
    sw $fp, 0($sp) # address of fp
    add $t0, $zero, $zero # j = 0
calc_for:   
    slt $t6, $t0, $a1 # $t6 = ($t0 < $a1) 
    beq $t6, $zero, calc_endfor # if ($t0 >= $a1) goto endfor
    
    sll $t1, $t0, 2 # $t1 = 4j
    add $t1, $a0, $t1 # $t1 = &input[j]
    lw $t1, 0($t1) # $t1 = input[j]
    
    sll $t2, $t1, 2 # $t2 = 4$t1
    sub $t3, $sp, $t2 # $t3 = &temp[input[j]]
    lw $t2, 0($t3) # $t2 = temp[input[j]]
    addi $t2, $t2, 1 # $t2++
    sw $t2, 0($t3) # $temp[input[j]] = $t2
    
    addi, $t0, $t0, 1 # j++
    j calc_for # goto for
calc_endfor:
    move $v1, $t1 # $v1 = input[j]
    lw $v0, 0($sp) # $fp regenerated
    addi $sp, $sp, 4 # free($fp)     
    jr $ra # return address of temp list 
    
# void count_sort_fill_values (int *input, int *temp, int i) {
#   int l = 0;
#   for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
#       for (int k = 0; k < temp[j]; k++) {
#           input[l] = j;           
#           l++;
#       }
#   }
# }

# $a0: address of temp list
# $a1: max value of list + 1
# $v0: address of sorted list
 
count_sort_fill_values:
    addi $sp, $sp, -4 # malloc(sizeof(int *fp))
    sw $fp, 0($sp) # fp saved
    add $t0, $zero, $zero # j = 0
    add $t1, $zero, $zero # l = 0
fill_for:   
    slt $t3, $t0, $a1 # $t3 = (j < i)
    beq $t3, $zero, fill_endfor # if (j >= i) goto endfor
    
    add $t2, $zero, $zero # k = 0
    sll $t4, $t0, 2 # j = 4j
    add $t4, $a0, $t4 # $t4 = &temp[j]
    lw $t4, 0($t4) # $t4 = temp[j]
fill_for_2: 
    slt $t5, $t2, $t4 # $t5 = (k < temp[j])
    beq $t5, $zero, fill_endfor_2 # if (k >= temp[j]) goto endfor_2
    
    sll $t6, $t1, 2 # l = 4*l
    sub $v0, $sp, $t6 # $v0 = $output[l] 
    sw $t0, 0($v0) # output[l] = j
    addi $t0, $t0, 1 # l++
    
    addi $t2, $t2, 1 # k++
    j fill_for_2 #goto for_2
fill_endfor_2:
    addi $t0, $t0, 1 # j++
    j fill_for # goto for
fill_endfor:
    lw $v0, 0($sp) # $v0 = fp
    addi $sp, $sp, 4 # free(fp)
    jr $ra # return

# void print_list (int *output, int i) {
#   for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
#       printf("%d ", output[j]);
#   }
# }
#
# $a0: address of sorted list
# $a1: size of list

print_list:
    move $s0, $a0 
    add $t0, $zero, $zero # j = 0
print_for:  slt $t1, $t0, $a1 # $t1 = (j < i)
    beq $t1, $zero, print_endfor # if (j >= i) goto endfor
    
    li $v0, 1 # print integer
    move $a0, $t0 # j to be printed
    syscall
    
    li $v0, 4 # print string
    la $a0, snt # sentence to be printed
    syscall
    
    sll $t1, $t0, 2 # $t1 = 4*j
    add $t1, $s0, $t1 # $t1 = &list[j]
    li $v0, 1 # print integer
    lw $a0, 0($t1) # list[j] to be printed
    syscall
    
    li $v0, 1 # print string
    la $a0, nln # newline to be printed
    syscall
    
    addi $t0, $t0, 1 # j++
print_endfor:
    jr $ra # return
```

Comment: Have you read this code?  Tried to compile or run the C code?  You're showing some C code for a void function and speaking to return value in your title.  The C code has errors -- it won't work.  It is comparing an integer to a pointer in the first for-loop.

Comment: @ErikEidt what would be your contribution then?

Comment: In case it wasn't clear, I suggest you make the C code work, then translate that to assembly.  There's no point in translating code that won't compile / doesn't work into assembly.

Comment: @ErikEidt yeah true int* i in the function definition should be int i, i wrote wrong, but do you see any LOGICAL error?

Comment: Ok, I have also already pointed out the logical inconsistency of speaking to return value for a void function.

Comment: @ErikEidt what would your suggestion be then for returning array? how does a void function look at registers?

Comment: My suggestion is still to make it work in C and then translate to assembly later.  You cannot return a (value) array in C, you cannot accept a (value) array as parameter in C.  Assembly is the same.  You can only pass or return pointers.  So, make it work in C first, so you don't have to work on both the nuances of pointers vs. arrays vs. return values vs. "out" parameters, as well as frame pointer, prologue and epilogue all together at the same time.  Once you know what you want in C, you can focus on frame pointers and assembly parameter & return values.

Comment: @ErikEidt i didnt mean c arrays can be parameter or returning values at all. anyways, i am trying to implement frame pointer as the pointer, what should I change in my code so that it has access to all array elements? any idea?

Comment: Show either working C code or else both the caller (calling function, e.g. main) and the callee (called function) in assembly.  Without one of those, very hard to tell what you're trying to do.  If you were trying simply to pass a pointer to array as parameter, that's a simpler question than what is being asked here.

Comment: the error seems to be changed after i changed something in my code and now it looks like this. $v0 is now 1 and i think this was caused by incrementing $v0 by 1 (this is exactly the value of first element of temp array). for some mysterious reason it reads not the address saved in $fp but remains unchanged.